# В лице Директора Ивановой, - действующего или действующей?

Tags: грамматика

в лице Директора  филиала ТОО «ЧЧЧ», Ивановой Оксаны Петровны, действующ**его** (или действую**щей**) на основании генеральной доверенности

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

> ***...действующего*** или ***действующей?***

[***Из ответа  справочной службы русского языка Грамоты.ру:***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=282407)

> В строгой деловой речи принято формальное согласование, по мужскому
>   роду, т. к. в официальной документации на первое место выдвигается
>   информация о должности (безотносительно к полу лица):
>
> ***в лице директора Ивановой, действующего*** на основании...

Answer (score 1):

Согласование идет с "директором", поэтому - в мужском роде.

> *Из ответа справочной службы русского языка Грамоты.ру:*

Да тут Грамота опять перемудрила. При чем тут строгая деловая речь, если есть общее правило, что согласование идет по должности? А если бы директор оказался с фамилией Выпендрёжных или  Неишьсало? Что, и написать нельзя, не заглянув в паспорт или еще в какое место, где "мальчиков от девочков" отличают?